# Javassist with JDK 17

Tags: java, javassist, java-17

Javassist (version 3.28.0-GA) stopped working after upgrading from JDK 11 to 17.

Calling `CtClass#toClass` renders the following error:

```
  ...
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @63e31ee
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:159)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper$JavaOther.defineClass(DefineClassHelper.java:213)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper$Java11.defineClass(DefineClassHelper.java:52)
at javassist.util.proxy.DefineClassHelper.toClass(DefineClassHelper.java:260)
at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1240)
at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1392)
```

Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: The official API for adding a class to an existing context is [`MethodHandles.Lookup.defineClass(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass(byte%5B%5D)). So you need either, a Javassist function that settles on that method, or call `toBytecode()` on the `CtClass` and create the appropriate lookup object yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a well known problem with Javassist and JDK 16 and later (https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/369).

The solution mentioned in the ticket is to no longer use `CtClass.toClass()`:

> Please do not use `ctClass.toClass()` anymore, try to [use] `ctClass.toClass(neigborClass)` as replacement.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the API of ctClass.toClass(neighbor) with neighbor class located on the same package as ctClass. However I got error message saying "Class not in same package as lookup class: xxx has no permission to define the class". Is there maybe a sample of snippet code? thx